# Create WildcardQuery in Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene.net

i Use lucene.net v3.0.3 in c#

i create one query like this:

```
         var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);            
         BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
         var firstParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, firstKey, analyzer);
         var firstFilter = parseQuery(firstValue, firstParser);
         query.Add(firstFilter, Occur.MUST);
```

is query worck fine, but only when enter Full word
like apple - board

but i need strat search when enter Letter
so i use wildcardQuery like this

```
        WildcardQuery wildcardQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(firstKey, "*" + firstValue + "*"));
        query.Add(wildcardQuery, Occur.MUST);
```

that query show result when i enter any letter but when enter space result gone

i need one query That's a combination this result

please help me

Comment: Your using Lucene's standard analyzer, that has impact on both your indexed data (and your entered query if you use the Query parser).

So if you happen to index: "There was a table full of Apples" your analyzer will make a list of terms out of that which are also normalize and filtered of stop words, so you will somewhat have: "table", "full", "apple" in your index.

Comment: So when your constructing your Wildcard Query as "*table *" - there is none of the above terms that matches that. again if you put a parser around this it will remove your stop words from your query as well.

Note that it will also complain about your * in the beginning unless you configure your parser to allow that. This is because a basic leading wildcard search is just inefficient since it causes a full scan of your index. There are techniques around this, like reversing terms or using ngrams etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is sample fuzzy search
sry I was new in Lucene but it work

```
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FuzzySearchTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //
            // Initialize the Directory and the IndexWriter.
            //
            var dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex");
            Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(dirInfo);
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

            //
            // Add Documents to the Index.
            //
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            doc.Add(new Field("postBody", "my favorit animal is cat", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);

            writer.Optimize();
            writer.Commit();
            //writer.Close();

            //
            // Create the Query.
            //
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "postBody", analyzer);
            //This is Fuzzy  between 0.5f and 1.0f
            parser.FuzzyMinSim = 0.7f;

            //similor text for search
            Query query = parser.Parse("fevorit  cat");

            //
            // Pass the Query to the IndexSearcher.
            //
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, readOnly: true);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(query, 200);

            //
            // Iterate over the Results.
            //
            int resultsCount = hits.ScoreDocs.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} results", resultsCount);
            for (int ixResult = 0; ixResult < resultsCount; ixResult++)
            {
                var docResult = searcher.Doc(hits.ScoreDocs[ixResult].Doc);
                float score = hits.ScoreDocs[ixResult].Score;
                Console.WriteLine("Result num {0}, score {1}", ixResult + 1, score);
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", doc.Get("id"));
                Console.WriteLine("Text found: {0}" + Environment.NewLine, doc.Get("postBody"));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

please add nugets

```
Lucene.Net
configurationManager
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: thank you
With a little change, I got a good result

Comment: your welcome , but if my answer need edit please do edit my answer